# Orion content negotiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http-headers, fiware-orion

I think this issue is probably a bug.

When we post an "append" operation to Orion using XMLHttpRequest, the "accept" header is set to

> application/json; */*,q=0.01

the response is encoded using XML instead of JSON.

The workaround is to override the accept header using the "onBeforeSubmit" callback and to set the header accept to "application/json" MIME type.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your input. If you think it's a bug I encourage you to file it in Orion's github account (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/new).

Comment: Taking a look at the specs (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) it seems like the header is not well constructe. We still think that Orion may have problems reading this type of accept headers and we are looking into it. Thanks for your feedback!